# When connecting external SanDisk Extreme SSD, windows starts to lag

Tags: windows, ssd, external-hard-drive, windows-11, peripherals

This problem started for me 24 hours ago after about several days of inactivity.
Until then, I worked with the same configuration for few weeks since I purchaed the SanDisk Extreme 2T SSD.

When I powered on my laptop (Dell Inspiron 15 5579) I hardly culd use my keyboard and mouse. Every mouse movement was extremely lagging, and typing on the kb didn't always succeeded.

I suspected that there is some service or resources issue.
At first, I disabled the windows search serivce which was using execesive CPU resources.

It didn't help.

Then I decided to try to launch the system when 8the external SDD is disconnected.
System works fluently.

Reconnected the SSD - system retunred to lag state.

What can I do to solve this?

Windows version: Windows 11 Home 21H2 22000.795

Comment: Reformat the drive GPT/NTFS if you didn't already. Test again. Drives always arrive MBR/ExFAT for compatibility, but this is not a good single-platform format.

Comment: @Tetsujin what's the relevance of your comment here?

Comment: @TomYan - see if the reformat spits out any nasty errors, apart from anything else. Would help diagnose drive or potential USB/SATA connectivity issues.

Comment: Also check SMART data for the drive. Maybe it is failing.